# c# Xamarin SQLite.Net Serialized Mode not working properly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, xamarin, serialization

I am using the library **SQLite.Net-PCL** in Android and iOS and have just encountered an error. Maybe I misunderstood something but the SQLite documentation states:

> **Serialized**. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple
>   threads with no restriction.

However, when I share a connection over several threads, something seems to go wrong.

I wrote a test application. See below.

With "simultaneous" insertion, i get **SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: Misuse**.

Here's the full Exception:

> SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: Misuse at
>   SQLite.Net.PreparedSqlLiteInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
>   (System.Object[] source) [0x0016b] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj, System.String
>   extra, System.Type objType) [0x000fc] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj) [0x00012] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0  at
>   test.TestTask+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0 (System.Object aName)
>   [0x00052] in /Users/dev/Documents/Xamarin/TestRepo/test/TestTask.cs:49

If you look at the database afterwards, it even looks like there are duplicate records.

So my question is: Is the **Serialized Mode** not designed to use a single connection in multiple threads? Or is it a bug in the SQLite lib?

**TestTask.cs (shared by Android and iOS):**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Attributes;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;

namespace test
{
    [Table("test_class")]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("caption")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }
    }

    public static class TestTask
    {
        static Task taskA;
        static Task taskB;

        public delegate void OnMessage(string msg);

        public static void Init(ISQLitePlatform platform, string path, OnMessage onMsg)
        {
            var con = new SQLiteConnection(platform, path);
            con.CreateTable<TestClass>();
            taskA = GetTask("First", con, onMsg);
            taskB = GetTask("Second", con, onMsg);
        }

        static Task GetTask(string name, SQLiteConnection connection, OnMessage onMsg)
        {
            return new Task((aName) =>
            {
                int i = 0;
                onMsg("Start " + aName);
                for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    var obj = new TestClass
                    {
                        Caption = i + ": " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff")
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Insert(obj);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        onMsg(aName + " -> " + "Index: " + i + " Error: " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
                onMsg("End " + aName);
            },name);
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            taskA.Start();
            taskB.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage (iOS example):**

```
    void HandleOnMessage(string msg)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(() => Console.WriteLine(msg));
    }

    void DoIt()
    {
        var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS.SQLitePlatformIOS();
        platform.SQLiteApi.Config(ConfigOption.Serialized);

        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        path = Path.Combine(path, "test.db");

        TestTask.Init(platform, path, HandleOnMessage);
        TestTask.Run();
    }
```

**Additional info:**

- I'm getting the same issue in Android Simulator and Android Device
- I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 7.4.3 (Build 10)
- I'm debugging on an iPhoneX Simulator with iOS 11.3

Comment: I've updated my question with the full exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I‘ve solved it myself.

It‘s a problem in the "SQLite.Net PCL" Nuget Package.

Use "sqlite-net-pcl" instead with Read|Write|FullMutex Flags at the Connection.
The FullMutex flag is forcing the serialized mode.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some code example about how are you setting up the flags at the connection? Thanks.